# Select multiple cells in DataGrid and output to Excel sheet

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I have a DataGrid with hundreds of rows and two columns of data. I will need to programmatically select a certain rows and some specific cell in a DataGrid and output them on an Excel worksheet.
After doing some research, it seems the only way to get a Cell Value is to write a helper function, and the helper function gets run each time you get a ONE cell value.

Is there a easier/quicker way to get value of a specific cell in a DataGrid? Or Am I supposed to store each cell value to an array concurrently when it goes to a DataGrid and output the array to Excel instead of the DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say that the `DataGrid`displays employees information, for each employee we store his `Id`, `Name` and `Address`. Lets add an additional Boolean property for each employee property (e.g. `Id` and `IsIdSelected`, `Name` and `IsNameSelected`) this Boolean property will be bound to the `DataGrid.IsSelected` property, thus, it represents whether the cell is selected or not, you could also use it to select the cell displaying the designated property programatically by setting it to `True`. See the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class that represents an employee. Notice that with each property
/// (e.g. Id) there is a Boolean property that has a similar name (e.g. IsIdSelected)
/// this Boolean property will be bound to the relevant DataGridCell.IsSelected
/// property to indicate whether the cell representing this property were selected
/// or not. In other words if you want to know the selected properties at any moment
/// you just need to iterate through the employees collection, and examine each
/// Boolean property for each property :D
/// </summary>
public class Employee
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsIdSelected { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsNameSelected { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsAddressSelected { get; set; }
}
```

The code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace CellSelection
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The DataGrid will be bound to this collection
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<Employee> _collection;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize the employees collection with some test data
            _collection =
                new ObservableCollection<Employee>
                    {
                        new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "Mohammed A. Fadil", Address = "..."},
                        new Employee {Id = 485, Name = "Khalid Zein", Address = "..."},
                        new Employee {Id = 64, Name = "Ahmed Mubarak", Address = "..."},
                        new Employee {Id = 364, Name = "Ali Ebraheim", Address = "..."},
                    };

            DataContext = _collection;
        }

        private void OnExportButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Now, concatinate all the selected cells
            var str = string.Empty;
            foreach (var emp in _collection)
            {
                if (emp.IsIdSelected)
                    str += string.Format("{0}, ", emp.Id);

                if (emp.IsNameSelected)
                    str += string.Format("{0}, ", emp.Name);

                if (emp.IsAddressSelected)
                    str += string.Format("{0}", emp.Address);

                str += "\n";
            }
            // Instead of displaying this message you could export these cells to Excel
            // in the format you need.
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="CellSelection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="275*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="36*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Path="IsIdSelected" Mode="TwoWay"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Path="IsNameSelected" Mode="TwoWay"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Path="IsAddressSelected" Mode="TwoWay"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Export Selection" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Click="OnExportButtonClick" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that for each `DataGrid` column you have to add a `CellStyle` that binds each column designated Boolean property to it's `DataGridCell.IsSelected` property, set this binding mode to `Mode="TwoWay"` in-order to support selecting cells programatically (In this case you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Employee` class).

With this solution you neither need the helper function nor to access the `DataGrid` actual cells any more, just iterate through your collection, determine the selected properties and process them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Clipboard class in the past where you can get comma separated values from the grid and then save it as CSV and then open it from Excel. I guess it might depend what kind of Grid Control you using

[MSDN On Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx)